# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:1452 While generating configurable products from Magento 2 dashboard

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

When I try to generate configurable products from Magento dashboard, I am getting the sql error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`admin_raba`.`catalog_product_website`, CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID_STORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `store_website` (`website_id`) ON DE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_website` (`product_id`,`website_id`) VALUES (?, ?) tried checking the catalog_product_website table. seems no problem. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am in the same boat. Everything I am seeing is related to not having a Store with id 0.